# Multiple references to the same model in another model in Django

Tags: django-models, foreign-key-relationship

Hi I have a lot of users in my system who are classified into different types. I want to store the address details of all those users. For instance the user could be a student, a school or a franchisee. All the users here could have an address information associated with them.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.Models import User

class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    address = models.TextField()

class Student(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)

class School(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    contact_person_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In this scenario there are 2 references to the User model - one through user_id and another through address.user though they should be referring to the same instance. Is it a bad practice to have duplicate references?

I thought of leaving out the 'user' foreignkey in Address, but I think that the address can't exist without a user. How to better model this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned in question duplication of same field in
a model is not a good Idea.

If these are your actual models, I would suggest you using [abstract
models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.Models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")
    address = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Student(Profile):
    pass

class School(Profile):
    contact_person_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

This will generate two tables: students, schools with fields
user, address and user, address, contact_person_name
respectively.

Comment: Hi @crodjer, in a totally different scenario where I'd like to store a user's expenses and categorize them, how can I use the same concept that you have explained? Each expense record will have be associated with a user. For each expense the user will have to associate one of the categories that he has created. So I'll have something like `Category(user, name)` and `Expense(user,amount,category)`. But the user reference is duplicated here. Since there is no sharing, I guess I can't use an abstract class.

Comment: Since address of a school and address of a student are similar information, shouldn't they be stored in one table instead of 2 as in the above example with abstract classes?